# How to use css selector with class prefix by dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Assume there are following divs

```
<div class="group1 section1" />
<div class="group1 section2" />
<div class="group1 section3" />
<div class="group1 section4" />

<div class="group2 section1" />
<div class="group2 section2" />
<div class="group2 section3" />
<div class="group2 section4" />
```

Now I have to select all  4 group 1 divs by Dojo, how to work this out

Comment: This should give you the elements with class group1. `dojo.query(".group1")`[Source](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dom.query('.group1');`

```
require([
    'dojo/query'
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (dom) {
    var group1 = dom.query('.group1');
});
```

Comment: the correct module to use is 'dojo/query', and should be used like this : require(['dojo/query','dojo/domReady!'], function(query) { query('.group1'); });